# Giving parameters when debugging code in Xamarin Studio

Tags: mono, xamarin, xamarin-studio

[image]

I can use Custom Parameters for giving parameters for running a program. However, when I start debugging the parameter setup doesn't seem to work.

How can I give the parameter in debugging mode with Xamarin Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The setup is in `Project Options`.